# Oracle - Concatenate calculated number field with string field

Tags: sql, oracle

In this case statement below, I want the result to be a string, either '*n* days' or '*n* weeks' based on the conditions in the statement.

How can I concatenate the number generated from `ABS(FLOOR(TRUNC(i.schedule_finish) - TRUNC(sysdate)))` with a string (that is, ' days' or ' weeks') to generate a string result?

Everything I've tried has given me an "inconsistent datatypes" error.

```
CASE
    WHEN ABS(FLOOR(TRUNC(i.schedule_finish) - TRUNC(sysdate))) < 7 THEN ABS(FLOOR(TRUNC(i.schedule_finish) - TRUNC(sysdate)))
    ELSE ABS(FLOOR((TRUNC(i.schedule_finish) - TRUNC(sysdate)) / 7))
END OVERDUE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `||`:

```
(CASE WHEN ABS(FLOOR(TRUNC(i.schedule_finish) - TRUNC(sysdate))) < 7
      THEN ABS(FLOOR(TRUNC(i.schedule_finish) - TRUNC(sysdate))) || ' days'
      ELSE ABS(FLOOR((TRUNC(i.schedule_finish) - TRUNC(sysdate)) / 7)) || ' weeks'
 END) as OVERDUE
```

Comment: Only had it on one case so one was returning a string and the other a number... My bad. This works. Thanks.